# creating instance of the class

Tags: c#

I was about to start learning C# and came across [zetcode C# tutorial](http://zetcode.com/lang/csharp/) (any suggestion for the nice tutorial website or pdf is appreciated). Since I was doing some programming using Python before, I found C# not so difficult. But, one thing I little confusing to me is the use of something like this taken from that website.

```
using System;

public class Being {}

public class CSharpApp
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Being b = new Being();// I don't understand this
        Console.WriteLine(b);
    }
}
```

Why not just:

```
b=new Being ();
```

Why is the website using the name of the class while in two places? Is it just the way C# is or is it one way of writing it?

Comment: Please continue reading tutorials, this is _extremely_ basic stuff.

Comment: You can use `var b = new Being();` too ;-)

Comment: You have to declare the type of the object before it can be instantiated.  For example `Being b; b = new Being();` would work, but it's easier to simply use `Being b = new Being();`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

well, you have 2 parts to it there.

The first part is the declaration of `b`

```
Being b;
```

Which essentially tells the compiler that you're going to be using a variable of type `Being` with the name `b`

---

The second part is the assignment of `b`

```
b = new Being();
```

Which assigns the variable `b` with an object, which in this case, is a new instance of the `Being` class

---

c# allows you to combine both parts into 1 line, resulting in the following:

```
Being b = new Being();
```

Comment: +1.  It might also be worth noting for completions sake that sometimes you want a different reference.  If `Being` implemented an interface, we might want that explicitly... `ICommonInterface b = new Being()`.

Answer (score 4):

The first "Being" defines the *type* of the variable `b`. This says that "`b` is a reference to an object of type `Being`". You could change this to `var b = Being()` and the compiler will infer the type of `B` based on the expression on the right hand side of the equals sign.

The second "Being" is part of an expression that provides the initial *value* of the variable `b`. In this case, it's a call to the default constructor `Being()`. You could assign the value of `b` in many ways:

```
Being b = null; // don't give it any value yet
Being b = new Being(); // make a new Being object using the default constructor
Being b = new Being("abcde"); // use a different custom constructor
Being b = GiveMeABeing(); // call some other method that will return a Being object
```

Answer (score 3):

The first `Being` in the variable declaration tells the compiler how it may identify and handle the object. The `new Being()` tells the compiler how to build (instantiate) the object. This sort of thing is useful when you leverage interfaces and subclasses.

```
abstract class IMusicalInstrument {
  public Play();
}

class Trumpet : IMusicalInstrument {
  public Play() {
    // etc.
  }
}

class Piano : IMusicalInstrument {
  public Play() {
    // etc.
  }
}
```

In doing so, you can leverage methods that return an unknown `IMusicalInstrument`:

```
IMusicalInstrument instrument = GetARandomInstrument();
```

.. And rest assured that you can `Play()` them, despite not knowing *exactly* what they are.

Answer (score 1):

The first line is defining a class

```
public class Being {}
```

and second code is creating an instance of that class.

```
Being b = new Being()
```

Comment: here is a link which describes what is a class and an object.
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/oop-concepts/objects-and-classes.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
b = new Being(); ?
```

I assume that you have knowledge about `=` operator which assigns rhs to lhs. In above statement you're assigning something to `b` right?

How does compiler knows what is `b`? Compiler has no idea what is `b`! So you have to say that `b` is a local variable of type `Being` that is what the following code doing

```
Being b;
```

Now nothing is in `b` You wanna store something in b in order to use it right? So create a instance of `type Being` and store it. that is what the following code doing

```
b = new Being();
```

We merge both and tell to compiler that `b` is of type `Being` and it holds new instance of `Being`.

```
Being b = new Being();
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

That's the way C# works. You need to give the name of the class. If you don't like that syntax - you can also do:

```
var being = new Being();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the type and then instantiate the type, so in your example you would specify that you want to declare a `Being` and then actually create (read: new up) a `Being` object.

As to your question of why you need to specify it twice, your declaration type could be a base class, but you instantiate a derived class, like this:

```
public class Animal {}

public class Human : Animal {}
```

Now in your code you could declare an `Animal`, but actually instantiate a `Human`, because a `Human` is an `Animal`, like this:

```
Animal myHuman = new Human();
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects in C# are modeled after real life objects. For instance, a ball has a radius, bounciness, weight, color, etc. You can also perform actions on a ball such as throwing, rolling, dropping, spinning, etc. In C#, you would create a class definition like this for a ball:

```
public class Ball
{
    // Radius in inches
    public double Radius { get; set; }
    public double Bounciness { get; set; }
    // Weight in lbs
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    // more properties

    // constructor - this is called when your class is instantiated (created)
    public Ball()
    {

    }

    // throw the ball
    public void Throw()
    {
        // method for throwing ball
    }

    // roll the ball
    public void Roll()
    {
        // method for rolling ball
    }

    // drop the ball
    public void Drop()
    {
        // method for dropping ball
    }

    // spin the ball
    public void Spin()
    {
        // method for spinning the ball
    }

    // more methods for interacting with a ball
}
```

Then you would declare an instance of Ball, set properties and call methods like this:

```
Ball ball = new Ball();
ball.Color = "Red";
ball.Weight = 1.2; // 1.2 lbs
ball.Radius = 12; // 12 inches
ball.Bounciness = 0.2; // for use in a physics engine perhaps
ball.Throw(); // throw the ball
ball.Drop(); // drop the ball
// etc
```